# Is there an Android RecyclerView Equivalent for html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create "cards" from an array of objects of type book in html. Each book object has title, author, a url with a image of the cover, a description, price and rating. I have to show each object separately on cards, each card must show the title, author and cover of the book. Once that card is clicked it takes us to another HTML page where you have more information about the book such as the description, the price, etc. This information must come from the previous page when the click is made. In android it is similar to making a Reciclerview with Cardview and populate it with an array of objects and that when clicking send information from one activity to another using SharedPreferences or Broadcast. The size of the array is unknown.